# identity and authorization Istio adapter not working

Tags: adapter, istio, mixer

I am trying to get a simple example of the App identity and Access Adapter for Istio working on Minikube.  I have followed the install instructions exactly and my calls to the sample application go through as if the adapter is no even there.

platform: minikube
istio installed via istioctl
adapter install via helm.
adapter pod is running

```
apiVersion: "security.cloud.ibm.com/v1"
kind:       OidcConfig
metadata:
  name:      oidc-provider-config
  namespace: default
spec:
  authMethod:   client_secret_basic
  discoveryUrl: https://us-south.appid.cloud.ibm.com/oauth/v4/
  clientId:     ******************************
  clientSecret: ******************************
```

```
apiVersion: security.cloud.ibm.com/v1
kind: Policy
metadata:
  name: sample-oidc-policy
  namespace: default
spec:
  targets:
    -  
      serviceName: service/helloworld
      paths:
        - exact: /hello
          method: ALL
          policies:
            - policyType: oidc
              config: oidc-provider-config
```

Comment: What is Your istio and minikube version? serviceName should be just helloworld i think.

Comment: Yeah I tried it without the "service/" first. minikube version: v1.6.2

Comment: And what is your istio version? Documentation for [App identity and Access Adapter](https://istio.io/blog/2019/app-identity-and-access-adapter/) was written assuming Istio 1.3, so some of this content may now be outdated.

Comment: istio is version 1.4.2.  I know that is newer than the documentation but not that much and I haven't seen anything about breaking changes to adapters.

Answer (score 2):

Did you set `global.disablePolicyChecks` to `false` and did you enable mixer during Istio install?

Mixer is disabled by default now.

See https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/installation-options/#mixer-options

Update:

I was just able to resolve this issue on my setup by doing the following:

First check the status of `disablePolicyCheck`:

```
kubectl -n istio-system get cm istio -o jsonpath="{@.data.mesh}" | grep disablePolicyChecks
```

If this returns `disablePolicyChecks: true` run

```
istioctl manifest apply --set values.global.disablePolicyChecks=false \
 --set values.mixer.policy.enabled=true \
 --set values.pilot.policy.enabled=true
```

Running the following should show the value of `disablePolicyChecks` as `false`

```
kubectl -n istio-system get cm istio -o jsonpath="{@.data.mesh}" | grep disablePolicyChecks
```

Comment: i have an api for security using oauth2 token , my flag disablePolicyChecks is false, once i configure another api with policy is just ignored, i can reach it without token, what could be the issue ?